If I want to write code in a register-level manner, which interrupt is enabled by default?
For example, if I want to write code without libraries, do I have to enable some system interrupts?
I know that in STM32-M3, the RESET, NMI, and Hard Fault interrupts are enabled by default. However, I want to check the status of system interrupts like Mem Manage, Bus Fault, and Usage Fault to see whether they are enabled by default or not.
I saw in the programming manual that these registers are initially filled with 0x0000 0000, but when I open Cube MX, these registers have their enable bits checked by default, and I didn't see anywhere in the project code where Cube MX initializes the NVIC or SCB registers for these interrupts.
That's why I'm a bit confused about where Cube MX has set them up.
Are they enabled at the hardware level?
Also, the reference manual states that they are configurable.
I would appreciate your guidance on where in the code generated by Cube MX these interrupts have been enabled.
Where does Cube MX initialize the corresponding registers?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Did you try to put some breakpoints and see after which function the bits in SCB are set? Did you try to create an empty while(1) project and check the SCB registers?
